# can i start async task without launching application?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am new to android programming. i am creating a application for Ecommerce. I want to call Async task for updating Sql database without launching my application. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Check out Background Services:
https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html

You could create background service with AlarmManager which would wake up every X hours/minutes and call your AsyncTask function. 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "launching my application". Your application process must be running for you to be executing code, such as an `AsyncTask`.

Answer (score 0):

What do you means by 'without launching my application'. You can always have AsyncTask in Service and your can start service whenever your app launches.

Comment: Please find my requirements below
1. Once my App is installed, I want to register a specific service.
2.this registered service should keep running at a scheduled time interval
3.It should run all the scheduled time irrespective of whether the application is launched or not
4.Also. It should trigger on automatically if a reboot happens.

Answer (score 0):

You must be looking for Android services http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html
.Services basically runs all over the time and runs in background.